# Passing Detail from tableview Controller

Tags: xcode, parse-platform

I am trying to push my detail view I am using a PFQueryTableView and I persume it was just same as normal so I was using this.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

// Check that a new transition has been requested to the DetailViewController and prepares for it
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"destinationViewController"]){

            // Capture the object (e.g. exam) the user has selected from the list
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
          dettailViewController *controller = (dettailViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;
           controller.clinics  = object;

}

}
```

But it bombs out at the *controller line I have a navigation controller on my storyboard.

When I say it bombs out it complains here

PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        vc.clinics  = object;
 and saids thread error

Comment: Something important, especially when you're starting out, is to paste in the actual full error message instead of trying to describe it in your own words.  Sometimes there are clues in the wording that you might not recognize as useful.

Comment: @PhillipMills i not sure how to do that in xcode i only have 13"macbook pro and the error line is always cut off to the right

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a nav controller you need to specify the navigation controller in your segue like so:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender

{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowDetail"]) {


    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UINavigationController *nav = [segue destinationViewController];
    EventDetail *detailViewController = (EventDetail *) nav.topViewController;
    detailViewController.event = object;
  }
}
```